# Reconnect after reboot

Tags: putty

Is it possible to keep putty 'alive' while im rebooting my remote computer? Of course with logging in again.

Means: I'm connected to my remote host via putty. I reboot the remote host via commandline and now I usually have to start putty again.

I've already ticked 'Enable TCP keepalives' and set 'Sending of null packets' to 600.

Comment: Note that all the options here will have you connect again, not reconnect to the existing session, which of course ceased to exist when the server rebooted, killing the ssh server and its sessions in the process.

Comment: @FrankThomas sure